# Can't detect webview Appium

Tags: c#, android, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to automate an hybrid phonegap application through Appium. While this app is running on a phone I can access it remotely through the Chrome browser. When I use Appium it doesn't show the webview context and only displays the native context. Is there a way to access the webview context and what am I doing wrong?

```
        var dirs = Directory.GetFiles("out", "*.apk");
        var app = Path.GetFullPath(dirs[0]);
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.SetCapability("fastReset", "True");
        cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.SetCapability("automationName", "Appium");
        cap.SetCapability("app", app);
        cap.SetCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        cap.SetCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
        AppiumDriver<AppiumWebElement> driver1 = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://192.168.1.138:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        Thread.Sleep(15000);
        var contexts = driver1.Contexts;
        foreach(string context in contexts)
        {
            if (context.Contains("WEBVIEW"))
            {
                driver1.Context = context;
                break;
            }
        }
        driver = driver1
```

Adding a log file as well:

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.4
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"Android","app":"locationApk.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","autoGrantPermissions":true},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"Android","app":"locationApk.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","autoGrantPermissions":true}]}}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"platformName":"Android","app":locationApk.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","autoGrantPermissions":true},null,{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"Android","app":locationApk.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","autoGrantPermissions":true}]},null,null]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1493796219386 (09:23:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time))
[Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver (v1.17.1) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   app: locationApk.apk'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'emulator-5554'
[Appium]   autoGrantPermissions: true
[AndroidDriver] AndroidDriver version: 1.17.1
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d
[AndroidDriver] Getting Java version
[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_131
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[ADB] Using adb.exe from C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[AndroidDriver] Using device: emulator-5554
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[ADB] Using adb.exe from C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[ADB] Setting device id to emulator-5554
[BaseDriver] Using local app 'locationApk.apk'
[AndroidDriver] Checking whether app is actually present
[AndroidDriver] Starting Android session
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","wait-for-device"]
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","echo","ping"]
[Logcat] Starting logcat capture
[AndroidDriver] Pushing settings apk to device...
[ADB] Getting install status for io.appium.settings
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","list","packages","io.appium.settings"]
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","list","packages","io.appium.settings"]
[ADB] App is installed
[ADB] Getting package info for io.appium.settings
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] Checking whether aapt is present
[ADB] Using aapt.exe from C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","dumpsys","package","io.appium.settings"]
[ADB] Cannot read version codes of C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\io.appium.settings\app\build\outputs\apk\settings_apk-debug.apk and/or io.appium.settings. Assuming correct app version is already installed
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","ro.build.version.sdk"]
[ADB] Device API level: 25
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","dumpsys","package","io.appium.settings"]
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","dump","io.appium.settings"]
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS",";","pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION",";"]
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS",";","pm","grant","io.appium.settings","android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION",";"]
[AndroidDriver] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","install","C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\appium-desktop\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-unlock\\bin\\unlock_apk-debug.apk"]
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","install","C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\appium-desktop\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-unlock\\bin\\unlock_apk-debug.apk"]
[ADB] Application 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-unlock\bin\unlock_apk-debug.apk' already installed. Continuing.
[ADB] Device API level: 25
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","appops","set","io.appium.settings","android:mock_location","allow"]
[ADB] Getting device platform version
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","ro.build.version.release"]
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","wm","size"]
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","ro.product.model"]
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.model': Android SDK built for x86
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","ro.product.manufacturer"]
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.manufacturer': unknown
[AndroidDriver] Parsing package and activity from app manifest
[ADB] Checking whether aapt is present
[ADB] Using aapt.exe from C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe
[ADB] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest
[ADB] badging package: nl.app.mobile
[ADB] badging act: nl.app.mobile.appMobile
[AndroidDriver] Parsed package and activity are: nl.app.mobile/nl.app.mobile.appMobile
[AndroidDriver] Remote apk path is /data/local/tmp/85f78b66b0710f626eacb402acfd93d2.apk
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","ls","/data/local/tmp/85f78b66b0710f626eacb402acfd93d2.apk"]
[AndroidDriver] Checking if app is installed
[ADB] Getting install status for nl.app.mobile
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","list","packages","nl.app.mobile"]
[ADB] App is installed
[AndroidDriver] Apk is already on remote and installed, resetting
[AndroidDriver] Running fast reset (stop and clear)
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","force-stop","nl.app.mobile"]
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","clear","nl.app.mobile"]
[ADB] Device API level: 25
[ADB] Checking whether aapt is present
[ADB] Using aapt.exe from C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe
[ADB] Extracting package and launch activity from manifest
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","dump","nl.app.mobile"]
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","pm","grant","nl.app.mobile","android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",";","pm","grant","nl.app.mobile","android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",";","pm","grant","nl.app.mobile","android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",";","pm","grant","nl.app.mobile","android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",";","pm","grant","nl.app.mobile","android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE",";","pm","grant","nl.app.mobile","android.permission.CAMERA",";","pm","grant","nl.app.mobile","android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",";"]
[AndroidDriver] Extracting strings from apk locationApk.apk undefined C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\nl.app.mobile
[ADB] Extracting strings for language: default
[ADB] Device API level: 25
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","persist.sys.locale"]
[ADB] Current device property 'persist.sys.locale': 
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","getprop","ro.product.locale"]
[ADB] Current device property 'ro.product.locale': en-US
[ADB] No strings.xml for language 'en', getting default strings.xml
[ADB] Reading strings from converted strings.json
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","push","C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\nl.app.mobile\\strings.json","/data/local/tmp"]
[AndroidBootstrap] Watching for bootstrap disconnect
[ADB] Forwarding system: 4724 to device: 4724
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","forward","tcp:4724","tcp:4724"]
[UiAutomator] Starting UiAutomator
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'starting'
[UiAutomator] Parsing uiautomator jar
[UiAutomator] Found jar name: 'AppiumBootstrap.jar'
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","push","C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\appium-desktop\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-android-bootstrap\\bootstrap\\bin\\AppiumBootstrap.jar","/data/local/tmp/"]
[ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","ps"]
[ADB] No uiautomator process found to kill, continuing...
[UiAutomator] Starting UIAutomator
[ADB] Creating ADB subprocess with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","uiautomator","runtest","AppiumBootstrap.jar","-c","io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap","-e","pkg","nl.app.mobile","-e","disableAndroidWatchers",false,"-e","acceptSslCerts",false]
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'online'
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] json loading complete.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
[AndroidBootstrap] Android bootstrap socket is now connected
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Client connected
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","dumpsys","window"]
[AndroidDriver] Screen already unlocked, doing nothing
[ADB] Device API level: 25
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","start","-W","-n","nl.app.mobile/nl.app.mobile.appMobile","-S"]
[ADB] Waiting for pkg: 'nl.app.mobile' and activity: 'nl.app.mobile.appMobile' to be focused
[ADB] Possible activities, to be checked: nl.app.mobile.appMobile, nl.app.mobile.nl.app.mobile.appMobile
[ADB] Getting focused package and activity
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","dumpsys","window","windows"]
[ADB] Found package: 'nl.app.mobile' and fully qualified activity name : 'nl.app.mobile.appMobile'
[Appium] New AndroidDriver session created successfully, session dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d added to master session list
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1493796234555 (09:23:54 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time))
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.createSession() result: {"platform":"LINUX","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"platformName":"Android","app":"locationApk.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","autoGrantPermissions":true},"platformName":"Android","app":"locationApk.apk","deviceName":"emulator-5554","autoGrantPermissions":true,"deviceUDID":"emulator-5554","platformVersion":"7.1.1","deviceScreenSize":"1080x1920","deviceModel":"Android SDK built for x86","deviceManufacturer":"unknown","appPackage":"nl.app.mobile","appWaitPackage":"nl.app.mobile","appActivity":"nl.app.mobile.appMobile","appWaitActivity":"nl.app.mobile.appMobile"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 15181 ms - 1018 
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d/contexts {}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getContexts() with args: ["dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d"]
[AndroidDriver] Getting a list of available webviews
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","cat","/proc/net/unix"]
[AndroidDriver] Found webviews: []
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP"]
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getContexts() result: ["NATIVE_APP"]
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d/contexts 200 93 ms - 86 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d/elements {"using":"xpath","value":"//*[contains(@id,'TutorialModeLogin')]"}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["xpath","//*[contains(@id,'TutorialModeLogin')]","dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d"]
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id,'TutorialModeLogin')]","context":"","multiple":true}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id,'TutorialModeLogin')]","context":"","multiple":true}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//*[contains(@id,'TutorialModeLogin')]' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d/elements - - ms - - 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d {}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d"]
[BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1493796309733 (09:25:09 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time))
[AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","force-stop","nl.app.mobile"]
[ADB] Pressing the HOME button
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","input","keyevent",3]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//*[contains(@id,'TutorialModeLogin')]' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopping'
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElements() result: []
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Closed client connection
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
[UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut down normally
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","ps"]
[ADB] No uiautomator process found to kill, continuing...
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","force-stop","io.appium.unlock"]
[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[Appium] Removing session dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d from our master session list
[BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionFinished' logged at 1493796311072 (09:25:11 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time))
[MJSONWP] Received response: null
[MJSONWP] But deleting session, so not returning
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.deleteSession() result: null
[HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session/dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d 200 1340 ms - 76 
[BaseDriver] Shutting down because we waited 60 seconds for a command
[AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[Appium] Closing session, cause was 'New Command Timeout of 60 seconds expired. Try customizing the timeout using the 'newCommandTimeout' desired capability'
[Appium] Removing session dd34fa43-e463-489b-9e47-567f20c36c5d from our master session list
[AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap wasn't active
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","am","force-stop","io.appium.unlock"]
[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
```

Found the reason why it wasn't detecting the webview. The app is build with phonegap and uses crosswalk. This causes the issue that Appium (under normal conditions) can't find a webview.

Comment: can you post your answer as an answer to the question? People might easily miss it the way it's stated right after the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing all the available context.sometimes the spellings or case might be different.following is the psuedo code.

```
foreach(string context in contexts)
{
    print(context)
}
```

Also check whthwr you have webview debugging enabked in code.

To do it use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately according to the server log there is only 1 context available if we look at the line `Responding to client with driver.getContexts() result: ["NATIVE_APP"]` So I don't think the problem is a naming issue

Comment: It is in debugging mode as the app I am testing has a indicator that it is in debugging mode and debugging mode has to be on for an app to be visible in the remote inspector in chrome